# Run length encoding of arbitrary length substrings

Tags: python, c, algorithm, encoding

What's efficient (in terms of both time complexity) [run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) algorithm for an arbitrary but finite length of input stream. An algorithm for substrings of length 1 can be implemented in C as:

```
void encoding(char *bytes)
{
    int c = 0; 
    char *s = bytes, ch;

    while(*s) {
       c=1;
       ch=*s;

       while(*s && *s== *(s+1)) {
          c++;
          s++;
       }
       printf("%d%c", c, ch);
       s++;
    }
}
```

However, I am looking for a better algorithm that can encode substrings of any length. For example, for the input `"abbabb"` the above code will print: `"1a2b1a2b"`. But a better algorithm could encode it as `"2abb"`.

The implementation language (C/Python is my choice) is not an issue as an algorithm is all I am looking for.

Comment: Without a restriction, the 'better' algorithm would always look ahead at least exactly half of the string plus one, and in a worst case scenario, the entire string length. (... At which point it just *may* end up with a 50% compression rate, which is not bad at all.)

Comment: Ah! That suggests a brute force "most greedy" algorithm: Given an input length of *n*, compare *n/2* with what follows, then compare *n/3*, and so on, until you reach a compare length of 1.

Comment: I am not sure if that's as straightforward (comparisons of n/2, n/3, etc). Because the sub string could start and end anywhere. For example, `abcdabcdaaaa` can be encoded as `2abcd4a` and the problem is how could I choose the `abcd` as the substring without scanning the input multiple times.

Comment: You're right. *n/2* is an upper limit for an exact `abcabc` match, but *n/3* is only valid (useful) for `ababab`. So start at *n/2* and step down by 1 element ... which will return `2abcd2aa`. Hm.

Comment: With this logic, an input such as `abbaabbabbaabbaabbabbab` can give us `2abbaabbabba1b` and also `2abba2b1a2abba2b1a1b` depends on how long the substring is. I think you should be more specific.

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad My question is a bit open ended. The better algorithm is the that encodes to least bytes, so I would choose `2abbaabbabba1b`. But I am looking for *any* algorithm as long as it the overall time complexity doesn't exceed O(n) even if the encoding is little inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

Any algorithm that can find a certain length repeated substring can be used to implement Lempel-Ziv compression with a sliding window of that length.

So I would look into Lempel-Ziv encoders and  use that. Or even better: drop the run length encoding and implement Lempel-Ziv - it can only provide better compression.

Comment: Never heard of [Lempel–Ziv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) before. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jongware My main answer is that you can look at the subsequence finding portion of Lempel-Ziv to solve the problem in his question. The suggestion to downright use LZ is just an afterthought.

Comment: Sorry :P You mean something as in http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77#LZ77? There is a good example in there.